# Chess tactics training

Tags: tactics, training

I am looking for a tactic training software for Windows/Linux/Symbian. I think that I know all tactics by now, and I want to train myself in using them. I do not want tactical software that separate their lessons, such as Chessimo. I want them to have an Elo system of sorts that gives harder puzzles for an higher Elo, and easier puzzles for lower Elo.

The only examples that I can think of are Tactic Trainer for Android and the chess.com Tactics. I am quite sure that there is a similar thing for Windows. Also please not online, I'm looking for software. Price is not a issue, at least 'til $50.

Thank you people in advance.

Comment: All I really need to say is: http://chesstempo.com/ :)

Comment: Thank you, but as I specified, I would like it offline. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

I thought this is the best for Windows: [http://www.amazon.com/CT-ART-Chess-Tactics-Training-Software/dp/1886846677](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1886846677)

Answer (score 3):

[Chess Hero](http://innokuo.altervista.org/chesshero.html) is a free program.  It does not select based on strength of puzzle but random choice, but I think it is the best offline trainer.

[Here](http://dejascacchi.altervista.org/exercises.htm) is a list of pdf files which are separated by difficulty.

If you want to invest the time, you could order a pgn/fen file from easiest to hardest.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tactics software that are very good.

Free:
chesstempo.com
lichess.org

Paid:
chess.com tactics 
CT-ARt

These are very common software and websites to improve tactics. Personally I like to use lichess.org because of the other uses it has like the study feature.