# From where to start learning new tactics?

Tags: learning, strategy, tactics

I know the basics and some basic tactics in chess, but I want to learn new and advanced tactics. Can anybody tell me any source for that?

Comment: Try Chessable site.

Comment: related, possible dupes: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/best-ways-for-improving-tactics and https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5730/chess-tactics-training

Comment: chess.com or chesstempo tactics training would be a good place.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried some of the existing sites that provide exercises.

If you are searching for common tactical position, [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/) is sure one of the best options with ilimitated free exercises.

If you are searching for incredible checkmates, sacs etc, [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/) has a nice trainer, the problem is it is not free.

You have also [lichess](https://lichess.org/). The exercises at this site are taken from blitz games of the players. They use stockfish to generate them. Some of them are doubtful, but a punctuation system is doing his task.

If you want to become a good player in long games (90+30) I recommend you to do lots of exercises at chesstempo, but lichess exercises are nice for tricks and so and totaly free.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of sites with random puzzles, but if you want to be systematic I recommend "Encyclopedia of Chess Middlegames: Combinations"
This is a large book of puzzles organized into 16 categories.  These types of puzzles also appear in any Chess Informant -- which also has endgame puzzles.

Comment: The problem I see, specialy for non advanced level @SpreadYourWings is it takes too much time to do the exercise and check the answer, but the book sure is great :)

Answer (score 1):

[chesstempo.com](http://chesstempo.com) is an excellent site for learning and practicing chess tactics. You can use it for free and the puzzles will adjust based on your success rate from easy to puzzles grandmasters get wrong.

Be sure to read the comments when you get a puzzle wrong as it often reveals some tactic type that you may have never seen before.

They also have a glossary of tactic types.

Answer (score 0):

A good source for newer players would be 303 tricky chess tactics by Wilson and Albertson. I'd recommend going through it multiple times until you can comfortably do about 50 problems a day with no mistakes. That's when you've really maximized what you can learn from that book. Once you can do that chess tempo would be the place to go for more advanced tactics.

Answer (score 0):

Seirawan's books are really informative and fun to read.

He has a Tactics book. It's great and it teaches tactical patterns is a very fun way, and I noticed myself winning with the same tactics I saw in the book a few days after reading them.